# C#: Unable to insert data in my Microsoft Access database

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access

I am unable to insert my data into my `Microsoft Access` database. Here below is my code:

```
            roomTableAdapter.Connection.Open();
            string s = "INSERT INTO `room` ([number], [priceroom]) VALUES (@param1,@param2)";
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(s, roomTableAdapter.Connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", textBoxX4.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", "4000");
            roomTableAdapter.Adapter.InsertCommand = cmd;
            roomTableAdapter.Adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            roomTableAdapter.Adapter.Fill(this.database3DataSet5);
            roomTableAdapter.Update(database3DataSet5.room);



            dataGridViewX1.Update();
            dataGridViewX1.Refresh();
            roomTableAdapter.Connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 roomTableAdapter.Connection.Open();
string s = string.Format("INSERT INTO `room` ([number], [priceroom]) VALUES  (@param1,@param2);");
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(s, roomTableAdapter.Connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", textBoxX4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", "4000");

roomTableAdapter.Adapter.InsertCommand = cmd;
roomTableAdapter.Adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
 roomTableAdapter.Adapter.Fill(this.database3DataSet5);
roomTableAdapter.Update(database3DataSet5.room);

 dataGridViewX1.Update();
dataGridViewX1.Refresh();
roomTableAdapter.Connection.Close();
```

Comment: Hello , it still can not insert data .in my new code What is wrong

Comment: Both fields seem - from their names - to be numeric, not text.

Comment: i defind that two fields "short text"  but still cannot update but gridview is updated? i should code authentication with admin?

Comment: i fix the problem by right click program and run administrator??? and run program in Debug folder it worked

Answer (score 1):

There should be no "ticks" in Access SQL. Thus:

```
string s = string.Format("INSERT INTO room ([number], [priceroom]) VALUES (?,?);");
```

Comment: Hello , it still can not insert data .in my new code What is wrong

Comment: i fix the problem by right click program and run administrator??? and run program in Debug folder it worked